# 0.9 < 0.9 is True in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, floating-point

I am working on a VB.Net project. Somewhere on the solution, I have this part of the code:

```
Dim my_variable As Single = 1

'other code goes here

If do_some_tests_here Then
   my_variable = 0.9
End If

If my_variable < 0.9 Then
   'do some other stuff here
End If
```

I realized that when the `my_variable` gets into the first `If` and changes it value to `0.9`, then the second condition `my_variable < 0.9` returns `True` and the code inside is executed.

I have read the comparing float numbers problems and that you should avoid it, but what is an alternative solution to the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem doesn't seems to arise if you change the variable from Single to Double. I think the compiler is turning the 0.9 into a double itself. but you can also turn the 0.9 into a single by using:

`If my_variable < CSng(0.9) Then`

or you can tell the compiler that it is a single by using the Letter F
 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters)

`If my_variable < 0.9F Then`

Comment: That was exactly the problem. When I compare the variable with the `0.9`, the latter is a double, while my variable was single. Both your solutions work.

Answer (score 2):

The literal `0.9` isn't exactly 0.9, but instead is the closest `Double` value, which is
0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625.

On the other hand, the closest `Single` value is
0.89999997615814208984375, which is less than the `Double` value.